Solve (underdetermined) linear system with commutator form in Python
Consider three (complex) square matrices A, X, and B, that form a generally underdetermined linear system
A @ X - X @ A == B
The system is to be solved for X. I would like to use, e.g., the lstsq functions of numpy or scipy to find a particular solution for X.
Note that in my case, A and B are Hermitian, and thus the solution X is necessarily anti-Hermitian.
It is of course always possible to use a custom least squares minimization, but is there a way to use existing linear algebra solvers to solve this directly?

You say that A and B are Hermitian. Does that mean you're working with complex numbers?

Yes, all matrices are complex.

Is this perhaps an attempted solution to the Heinsenberg relation? Is the right-hand side expected to be an identity?

Or more likely, this is a Lyapunov equation; but then the second instance of A would need to receive a conjugate transpose and you haven't shown that.

...Or even more generally, if there is no conjugate transpose, then this can be read as a Sylvester equation.

You talk of this being underdetermined linear system, yet you have AX and XA. Without a conjugate transpose, this only seems that the dimensionality of A and X are same and both are square matrices. But then that means its not underdetermined.... Either I am missing something or you missed something in the writeup

Thanks for the references, especially the Sylvester equation. I will look into it. However, it is indeed an underdetermined system, since you can add to the solution X any matrix that commutes with A and is still a solution.

Thanks to @Reinderien in the comments for the solution idea. Scipy has a solve_sylvester function specifically for this problem, namely,
import scipy

X = scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester(A, -A, B)

This could use optimizations for my case, but it will work well enough. Unfortunately, the function does not seem to support batching.
EDIT AND WARNING: As ThomasIsCoding points out in the comments, there might be issues with using the Bartels-Stewart algorithm (on which solve_sylvester is based) in my particular case. I checked that it worked in a very simple case. But then, in a very complicated case, it gave me nonsense. So tread carefully. I don't have time to investigate further at the moment.

I don't think this would give the desired X, since A and -A have the same eigen values when you are solving sylvester equation. You can verify the solution via checking if the equality holds.

I checked in a very simple case and it does work. The documentation says that it finds a solution to the equation, and that's all I need. Of course it's possible that this statement from the docs is inaccurate.
